# Three.js canvas is missing after switching pages with router in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, three.js, vue-router

I've a small site with just 3 page made you vue3, Vite and Vue Router
On the home compoment I load the three.js library that generate a canvas, I inizialize the canvas in the mounted hooks

The canvas load correctly in the dom at first page load but if I navigate in another page and the turn back to the home it disappear, there is no error in the console

I guess it could be something related to the router but I can't find a way to debug it

Comment: I have the exact same problem but with SvelteKit + Vite. Did you figure it out in the meantime?

Comment: @JJ77 unfortunately no, I kept it like that